# Decrease size of array in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Assume that I had an array:

```
real, dimension(100000, 5) :: a
```

This array will be filled by real numbers from `a(0, :)` till `a(n, :)` where `n` is a number that lesser than `100000`. After all values are filled then we can decide value of `n` (let's assume it `30000`). I want to reshape the array to:

```
real, dimension(30000, 5) :: a
```

just to remove unused elements in the array. I don't want any array copy process to be performed because the array is just large, so, it can ruin a program efficiency. Is there any resolution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do anything. There is nothing in the language to shrink an array. Especially not when you declared it as a fixed-size array in the first place. And since you forbid copying, there is really nothing you can do.

You didn't tell us why you want to do that. To save memory? It is a fixed-size array `real, dimension(100000, 5)`, it is simply there, you can't save anything. You could use an allocatable array, but for shrinking a *copy is necessary*.

Or just for easier work with the array? Do it like in the old FORTRAN 77 days, declare a variable `n` and use the array always as

```
a(:n,:)
```

To make it contiguous? You need to make it allocatable and allocate it to the right size.

To some extent your question is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you do not tell us what is the actual aim. You are just asking for some technical detail which might not be the best way to solve the final goal. Consider using an allocatable array and allocate it to the right size from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, my concern is about "memory" and "easier work with the array". but I think it  is unnecessary as you said. I am just used to the way to work with array that has a right size. As in Python, Java, etc. where you can use "for each loop" on array but you suppose to have an array with  size that really reflect to actual number of data.

Comment: Similar stuff (even better!) is possible in Fortran as well. You can do `a(:n,:) = 0` and you don't need any loop at all. There is also `where` and so on... (`forall` too, but now obsolete in Fortran 2015).